# Uniqueness of parameters in sum of parameterized functions

Tags: reference-request, taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have some family of functions $f(x;\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a parameter. Given the following equality

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n f(x;\alpha_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x;\alpha_i'), $$

for all $x$ in some interval, under what circumstances do the $\alpha_i$ equal the $\alpha_i'$ (up to permutation)?

This will obviously depend on the family of functions, but it would be nice to find a reference where examples of such problems are addressed. If you know of one please let me know.

A specific example:

$$ f(x;\alpha,\beta) = \frac{x^2 \alpha (1-\beta)^2}{1 - x\beta} - \ln(1 - x\beta) - x(\alpha(1-\beta) - \ln(1-\beta)) $$

with $|x| < 1/|\beta|$. So, given

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n f(x;\alpha_i,\beta_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x;\alpha_i',\beta_i'), $$

is it possible to show that the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ equal the $\alpha_i'$ and $\beta_i'$ respectively, up to permutation? I believe it is necessary to assume that all $\beta_i$ values are distinct.

My idea so far is take the Taylor expansion around $x=0$. Considering only the coefficient of the $x^k$ term, this takes the form

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \alpha_i (1-\beta_i)^2 \beta_i^{k-2} + \frac{\beta_i^k}{k} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \alpha_i' (1-\beta_i')^2 \beta_i'^{k-2} + \frac{\beta_i'^k}{k} \right), $$

for all $k \geq 2$. From here I'm stuck and would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: No expert here but I am sure you have to impose a lot of strong presumptions to make progress.  My experience with Real Analysis is that I could find a multitude of counterexamples.   Speaking from a DSP point of view; you are sampling and summing a function in one dimension.  The ability to overcome the summation and return to individual samples seems like a high hurdle and relativity tightly constrained.  I suggest looking at DSP theory where sampling of continuous functions is typical.

Comment: Or else look at "Interpolation & Approximation" by Davis.  An old book but a favorite of mine: https://www.amazon.com/Interpolation-Approximation-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486624951